# Uvcvideo trying to load a camera twice

Tags: linux-mint, camera

I've got a problem with uvcvideo, where I get this error at startup:

```
uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
```

which also shows up in `dmesg` if you unload and load the `uvcvideo` module (`modprobe -r uvcvideo & modprobe uvcvideo`)

When loaded, the `uvcvideo` driver has tried to load two cameras:

```
# ls -l /sys/bus/usb/drivers/uvcvideo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Nov 23 10:46 1-2:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Nov 23 10:46 1-2:1.1 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Nov 23 10:46 bind
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Nov 23 10:46 module -> ../../../../module/uvcvideo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 23 10:46 new_id
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 23 10:46 remove_id
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Nov 23 10:45 uevent
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Nov 23 10:46 unbind
```

but there is only one webcamera, which it tries to load two times and fails at.

The system is linux mint 17  with the 3.13.0-35-generic kernel.

Have I misunderstood what is happening?

How can I fix this?